# Showing a set of vectors is independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like to redo the proof by walkar (with fewer vectors) just to see if I can handle the algebra the way I do

[Proving that $(u+v,u+w,v+w)$ is linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701110/proving-that-uv-uw-vw-is-linearly-independent)

Suppose $au + bv = 0 \implies a = b = 0$. Then $av - bu = 0$. Adding the two equations we get $au + av -bu + bv = 0$ which implies $a(u + v) + b(u – v) = 0$ and since $a = b = 0, \{u + v, u – v\}$ is linearly independent.

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity $0(u+v)+0(u-v)=0$ is obvious, so you proved nothing at all.

You must start from $a(u+v)+b(u-v)=0$ *without no hypothesis on $a$ and $b$*.

Then you have $(a+b)u+(a-b)v=0$; if $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent, you can conclude $a+b=0$ and $a-b=0$. Therefore $2a=0$ and $2b=0$. If the characteristic is $\ne2$, this implies $a=b=0$.

Comment: I was thinking if $\{u, v\}$ is linearly independent, then $au + bv = 0$ such that $a = b = 0.$ Why can't we derive directly from the assumption that $\{u, v\}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: @user342625 You're thinking the wrong way; the set $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent if *from $au+bv=0$ it follows that $a=b=0$*. This is very different from stating the obvious fact that $au+bv=0$ if $a=b=0$.

Comment: @user342625 $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent if $au+bv=0$ *only if* $a=b=0$. The converse implication is obvious.

Comment: @ egreg, let some $\{s, t\}$ be linearly independent. Then...what can we say (without regard to the given problem) in general? Thanks.

Comment: @user342625 I don't understand: the two vectors form a linearly independent set, what else?

Comment: @ greg, I am having a little difficulty with the definition. The definition says $au + bv = 0$ with $a = b = 0 \implies \{u, v\}$ is linearly independent, but it doesn't say $\{u, v\}$ is linearly independent $\implies au + bv = 0$ with $a = b = 0$. Is that correct?

Comment: @user342625 No, the definition cannot say that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to show that whenever you any $a,b$ that satisfy $a(u+v)+b(u-v)=0$, you can conclude that $a$ and $b$ are both zeros.

In your working, you have only selected a very special pair of $a$ and $b$ that satisfies $au+bv=0$.